# ERROR: column "field" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration

I've hit an SQL problem that I'm a bit mystified by. I have two different
questions regarding this problem:

- Why?
- How do I work around it?

The following query:

```
SELECT subs.date_added,subs.subscribed_to,users.userid, users.username, users.email, users.avatar, users.fbuid, users.level, users.avatar_url, users.sex, users.dob, users.profile_hits, users.total_videos, users.subscribers, users.doj, users.extras, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.ban_status, users.usr_status, users.last_logged, users.country, users.user_filter_level, users.signup_ip, subs.userid as subscriber 
FROM cb_subscriptions as subs 
     LEFT JOIN cb_users AS users 
     ON subs.userid=users.userid 
WHERE subs.subscribed_to ='2960' 
GROUP BY subs.subscribed_to ,subs.userid 
ORDER BY subs.date_added ASC 
LIMIT 8;
```

...produces the following error:

```
ERROR: column "users.userid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

That field is a `CHAR`, so I'm not sure what kind of aggregate to use,
or (more important to my understanding) why one is necessary.

As I said, I'm not sure I understand why this occurs.  I'm assuming that I
don't understand `group by` as well as I thought I did ;)

This isn't my query, I'm translating a system prototyped in MySQL to
PostgreSQL.  This query *does* work in MySql.  Does that constitute a
bug in MySql, or a shortcoming of PostgreSQL, or just a difference of
interpretation?

And when I added this column in the `group by` clause it's working, but I don't understand why?

#### Working query

```
SELECT subs.date_added, users.userid, users.username, users.email, 
       users.avatar, users.fbuid, users.level, users.avatar_url, 
       users.sex, users.dob, users.profile_hits, users.total_videos,
       users.subscribers, users.doj, users.extras, users.first_name, 
       users.last_name, users.ban_status, users.usr_status, 
       users.last_logged, users.country, users.user_filter_level, 
       users.signup_ip, subs.userid as subscriber 
FROM cb_subscriptions as subs 
     LEFT JOIN cb_users AS users 
     ON subs.userid=users.userid 
WHERE subs.subscribed_to ='2960' 
GROUP BY users.userid, 
         subs.subscribed_to, 
         subs.userid, 
         subs.date_added 
ORDER BY subs.date_added ASC 
LIMIT 8;
```

#### cb_subscriptions DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `cb_subscriptions` (
    `subscription_id` int(225) NOT NULL,
    `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `subscribed_to` mediumtext NOT NULL,
    `date_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `cb_subscriptions`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`subscription_id`);

ALTER TABLE `cb_subscriptions`
  MODIFY `subscription_id` int(225) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

#### cb_users DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `cb_users` (
  `userid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `fbuid` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `category` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `user_session_key` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `user_session_code` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `usr_status` enum('Ok','ToActivate') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ToActivate',
  `msg_notify` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
  `avatar` varchar(225) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `avatar_url` text NOT NULL,
  `sex` enum('male','female') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'male',
  `dob` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `country` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PK',
  `level` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `avcode` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `doj` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_logged` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `num_visits` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `session` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `signup_ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `time_zone` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `featured` enum('No','Yes') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No',
  `featured_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `profile_hits` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `total_watched` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total_videos` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_comments` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `total_photos` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `total_collections` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `comments_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `last_commented` datetime NOT NULL,
  `voted` text NOT NULL,
  `likes` decimal(5,0) NOT NULL,
  `likes_count` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `ban_status` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `upload` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `subscribers` bigint(225) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total_subscriptions` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `background` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `background_color` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `background_url` text NOT NULL,
  `background_repeat` enum('no-repeat','repeat','repeat-x','repeat-y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'repeat',
  `background_attachement` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `total_groups` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `last_active` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `banned_users` text NOT NULL,
  `welcome_email_sent` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `total_downloads` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `is_subscribed` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `album_privacy` enum('public','private','friends') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'private',
  `extras` text NOT NULL,
  `user_filter_level` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `cb_users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
  ADD KEY `ind_status_doj` (`doj`),
  ADD KEY `ind_status_id` (`userid`),
  ADD KEY `ind_hits_doj` (`profile_hits`,`doj`),
  ADD KEY `username` (`username`);
```

Comment: Your SQL does not seem complete. The `GCP,` and `TLM.TLI_ID` indicated that you need another object.

Comment: Discussion **[moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78772/discussion-between-ypercube-and-imran).**

Comment: What versions of MySQL and PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: `userid` is `INT` in one table, `BIGINT` in the other -- not good.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> This isn't my query, I'm translating a system prototyped in MySQL to PostgreSQL. This query does work in MySql.
>   Does that constitute a **bug in MySql**, or a **shortcoming of PostgreSQL**, or just a **difference of interpretation**?

More like all of the above ;)

> Does that constitute a **bug in MySql**?

It's a "feature" that many consider a bug. Mainly because it can be misused, much like you (or whoever wrote the first query) misused it.

The correct use of the feature is to have a "shorter" `GROUP BY` clause. Any column that **is functionally dependent** on the `GROUP BY` columns can be omitted from the `GROUP BY` list and freely used in `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` without aggregates.

So, if there is a unique constraint on `subs (subscribed_to, userid)`, then your 1st query is valid SQL - according to some (2011 or 2013) added feature for `GROUP BY`).

Your DDL definitions do not have such `UNIQUE` constraint, so it's misuse from your developers. The reason that it produces correct results (if it does), is likely that the data conform to such a `UNIQUE` constraint, although it is not enforced. It seems plausible that a user can have only one subscription to a magazine (or whatever that `subscribed_to` refers).

It's also possible that your data do not conform to such a constraint, in which case **the query has been giving you wrong results - and you just haven't noticed!** Check your data and the output of the query (in MySQL). Do you have many subscriptions for the same (magazine or whatever) and the same user? In those case, which `date_added` is returned? And ask the business users (whoever knows the requirements of the query), which `date_added` should be returned? The last one (of the many from a user and magazine)? The first one? A random one?

The rest of the columns (from `users` table) in the `SELECT` list are actually correctly shown, as the join between the two tables is on `userid` which appears on the `GROUP BY` list and has a `UNIQUE` constraint on `users`.

Please also note that MySQL does not really check all these things (at least until version 5.6). It's the developers' responsibility that the feature is correctly used. And since it is so complicated to get it right, it's no wonder that it is widely misused, giving incorrect or inconsistent or even plainly inexistent results in many cases. That's why many people considered it a bug. (The feature has been widely improved in version 5.7 of MySQL.)

> Does that constitute a **shortcoming of PostgreSQL**.

Not really. Postgres has implemented the same feature, but slightly differently - more restrictedly than MySQL. Postgres only uses it when the `GROUP BY` columns have the `PRIMARY KEY` of one (or more) tables. In that case, you can use the freely rest of the columns (of those tables) in the `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` lists without aggregates. It doesn't work with `UNIQUE` constraints and it doesn't work with (provable) constraints from foreign keys.

> Does that constitute a **difference of interpretation**?

As explained above, yes. The two DBMS have implemented the feature differently, so the query is interpreted differently.

MySQL (up to 5.6) says *"I don't care, I'll give you some results. You are responsible if they are not correct)"*

Postgres says *"I'll only give you results if I'm 100% sure that they are consistent and correct."*

---

> So, what to do so the query works correctly?

We have two issues:

- For the `users` table, it's simple: add `users.userid` in the `GROUP BY` list.
- For the `subs` table and the `date_added` column, it's important to know what results your users want/expect. If they want the earliest date (per `user` and `subscribed_to`), then use `MIN(date_added)`. If they want the latest, use `MAX(date_added)`.

The query becomes - and works correctly in all MySQL and Postgres versions:

```
SELECT MIN(subs.date_added) AS min_date_added, 
       users.userid, users.username,      --- any users column you need
       --- 
       subs.userid AS subscriber 
FROM cb_subscriptions AS subs 
     LEFT JOIN cb_users AS users 
     ON subs.userid = users.userid 
WHERE subs.subscribed_to = '2960' 
GROUP BY users.userid, 
         -- subs.subscribed_to,    -- not needed really, it's fixed in WHERE
         subs.userid 
ORDER BY min_date_added ASC 
LIMIT 8 ;
```

Comment: "Before 5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default." -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html  "Functional dependence" checks were close to perfect in 5.7.8.